# Multiple Adapters Single Store Issue

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to use different Adapters for 2 different Ember Models but this setup seems to be having problems. I'm able to fetch(find) the 2 models using their respective adapters but when i try to save(commit) them, an issue arises and both try to use the first model's adapter only.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ember-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ember-data-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">
    <h1>Application</h1>
    {{ outlet }}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <b>Create</b>
    <a href="#" {{action "createOne"}}>Create One</a>
    <a href="#" {{action "createTwo"}}>Create Two</a>
    <hr>
    <b>Load</b>
    <a href="#" {{action "loadOne"}}>Load One</a>
    <a href="#" {{action "loadTwo"}}>Load Two</a>
    </script>

    <script>
    App = Ember.Application.create();

    App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
        revision: 12,
        adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
            url: "/one"
        })
    });

    App.Store.registerAdapter("App.Two",DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        url: "/two"
    }));

    App.One = DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr("string",{defaultValue:"one"})
    });

    App.Two = DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr("string",{defaultValue:"two"})
    });

    App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
        createOne: function() {
            App.One.createRecord({}).save();
        },

        createTwo: function() {
            App.Two.createRecord({}).save();
        },

        loadOne: function() {
            App.One.find();
        },

        loadTwo: function() {
            App.Two.find();
        }
    });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Load One and Load Two links work well and hit the url's **GET one/ones and GET two/twos** respectively. But On using Create One and Create Two links the links hit are **PUT one/ones and PUT one/twos. and not one/ones and two/twos**. So Ember is trying to hit the second click of creating two with One's adapter and not changing it to Two's Adapter.

Any idea anyone ?